# Memory issues when copying JPEG into bmp

Tags: c#, memory-management

I am trying as a part of a bigger job to merge parts of several JPEGs into one huge BMP which will be processed further.

As a start, I tried to just copy a few JPEGs each to his own BMP file. In doing so I noticed that Visual Studio 2015 Community shows increased memory consumption if I repeat the copying of files in a single debug-run. The responsible part of the code is as follows.

Please, can you help me with this increasing memory consumption? In the future, I might need to read a few thousand JPEGs so this might be a serious issue.

```
private void GluePhotos(string[] files) {
    foreach (string file in files) {
        //Read original JPEG
        Stream imageSource = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        JpegBitmapDecoder jpegDecoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = jpegDecoder.Frames[0];

        //Prepare memory
        int stride = bitmapSource.PixelWidth * ((bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
        byte[] pixels = new byte[bitmapSource.PixelHeight * stride]; 

        //Copy JPEG into memory
        bitmapSource.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

        //Copy memory into a new BMP-to-be
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight, bitmapSource.DpiX, bitmapSource.DpiY, bitmapSource.Format, bitmapSource.Palette);
        bitmap.WritePixels(new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight), pixels, stride, 0);

        //Encode it as a BMP
        BmpBitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        BitmapFrame newBitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(newBitmapFrame);

        //Prepare paths for saving, save and cleaning(?)
        string dirPath = file.Insert(file.LastIndexOf('\\'), "\\ripoffs");
        dirPath = dirPath.Remove(dirPath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
        string fileName = file.Insert(file.LastIndexOf('\\'), "\\ripoffs");
        fileName = fileName.Remove(fileName.LastIndexOf('.')) + "_ripoff.bmp";
        Stream imageOutput = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        bmpEncoder.Save(imageOutput);
        imageOutput.Close();
        imageSource.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without even looking at your code my guess is you are not disposing

Comment: @Paparazzi Close = Dispose, Dispose = Close

Comment: It is in C#, i.e. garbage collection is here, but I am not sure if I do not unintentionally keep something open/in memory/... and if yes, then what?

Comment: Disposing of an object (closing) **does not release memory**. This is the way the C# garbage collector works! You aren't going to get an actual garbage collection until there is memory pressure. You can try to force this through a call to `GC.Collect()` but I would advise only for debugging/testing purposes. You may be trying to chase a problem that doesn't exist, try testing with multiple files, I think you'll find that it will increase to a point and then stabilize as the GC starts collecting.

Comment: @RonBeyer Okay, I suppose you are true, especially with a ' ... it will increase to a point ...'. I tried repeatedly processing same 5 files and found that even after GC kicks in a small but measurable increase in memory consumption took place. But probably it will saturate after some time, as you pointed out.

Comment: Try explicitly setting stuff like bitmapSource   = null;    You should not have to do that but at this point just something to try.

Comment: I think there is nothing to worry about. You dispose everything that should be disposed and if the memory usage drops after some time then the garbage collector kicks in. If you process a lot of data then it needs memory. I wouldn't care unless you're out of RAM.

Comment: **Use a memory profiler to answer questions about memory**.

Answer (score 1):

If you need comments to document the flow of your method, then you're doing it wrong. Obviously this needs to be split into much smaller methods, each dedicated to their own logic.

That was you could move the three lines below `//Read original JPEG` to a method of their own that would return a BitmapSource<del>, and you could encapsulate `imageSource` in a `using` block (considering it's an `IDisposable`)</del>.

<del>Same for `imageOutput`: another stream you're not properly disposing of.</del>

Quite frankly, I'd move everything inside the `foreach` into a class of its own and start refactoring from there.

---

I had to look up what this does:

```
string dirPath = file.Insert(file.LastIndexOf('\\'), "\\ripoffs");
```

I can't help but feel that this is a hacky way of something that should be done with for instance `FileInfo` and `Path` etc;

Consider this (I'm assuming `file` is a global variable of the class that contains all of the code in the `foreach`):

```
    private string GetResultPath()
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

        var directoryPath = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
        var newDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "ripoffs");

        Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectoryPath);

        var fileName = fileInfo.Name.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, string.Empty)
                                   + "_ripoff"
                                   + fileInfo.Extension;

        return Path.Combine(newDirectoryPath, fileName);
    }
```

Yes, that's longer, but it's also much clearer and informs the next developer who looks at that code what it does.

Comment: As for a first part, of your answer, I am a bit confused by the `using`behaviour. I thought that `using(Stream s = ...) { ... }` does the same as `Stream s = ... //crunching ... s.close();`. However, thanks for your ideas. I planned to go for refactoring later since this is my first attempt at manipulation of JPEGs/BMPs/... and converting them to and from.

Comment: @Rao Yes, that does appear to be the case. However, you're leaving `imageSource` open for too long; no need to keep it open until the end.

Comment: Try changing `BitmapCacheOption.Default` to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` and see what that does for your memory footprint.

Comment: @Rao - no, `using` is equivalent to `try { stream = ... } finally { stream.Dispose() }`. I.e. `Dispose` will get called even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Oh, yes, Exceptions slipped from my mind. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably OK and it will be cleaned up in garbage collection
A stretch but maybe give this a try

```
public void bmap(string[] files)
{
    Stream imageSource;
    BitmapSource bitmapSource;
    int stride;
    byte[] pixels;
    WriteableBitmap bitmap;
    System.Windows.Int32Rect rect;
    BmpBitmapEncoder bmpEncoder;
    BitmapFrame newBitmapFrame;
    Stream imageOutput;
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        imageSource = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);            
        JpegBitmapDecoder jpegDecoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        imageSource.Close();
        bitmapSource = jpegDecoder.Frames[0];

        //Prepare memory
        stride = bitmapSource.PixelWidth * ((bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
        pixels = new byte[bitmapSource.PixelHeight * stride];

        //Copy JPEG into memory
        bitmapSource.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

        //Copy memory into a new BMP-to-be
        bitmap = null;
        bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight, bitmapSource.DpiX, bitmapSource.DpiY, bitmapSource.Format, bitmapSource.Palette);
        rect = new System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight);
        bitmap.WritePixels(rect, pixels, stride, 0);

        //Encode it as a BMP
        bmpEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        newBitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(newBitmapFrame);

        //Prepare paths for saving, save and cleaning(?)
        string dirPath = file.Insert(file.LastIndexOf('\\'), "\\ripoffs");
        dirPath = dirPath.Remove(dirPath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
        string fileName = file.Insert(file.LastIndexOf('\\'), "\\ripoffs");
        fileName = fileName.Remove(fileName.LastIndexOf('.')) + "_ripoff.bmp";
        imageOutput = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        bmpEncoder.Save(imageOutput);
        imageOutput.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one thing: I tried something similar but with `using`s. And if a ended before the line with `CopyPixels`, my output picture got corrupted. More precisely, part from beginning (line-wise) is okay, but after some point, it was only a colour (one for whole rest) and nothing more. Ending `using` after `CopyPixels` solved this.